# After upgrade: what's this envelope systray icon, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, system-tray

I've just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and everything seems to be running fine. I have a couple new icons in my systray, though, and one of them -- the envelope icon -- is a mystery to me:

[image]

It looks like a chat notifier (clicking it gives "Available", "Away", "Busy", etc., indicators) but I don't use Pidgin (never have), or it could be an email indicator but I don't use Thunderbird (never have). There's nothing else I can see (left- or right-clicking) that identifies it.

I'd like to get rid of it, but "Startup applications" only lists the ones I have optionally added, and this is not among them.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just remove it a few days ago by running the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages -y
```

A re-login is necesary.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the Mail icon, open the Terminal, and copy & paste the command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove indicator-messages
```

Now press Enter and enter your password, then press Enter once again

Now you need to restart lightdm with the following command in the Terminal

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Press Enter and enter your password then press Enter, lightdm will flash and the Mail icon will no longer show.

### Credit to [scouser73](https://askubuntu.com/users/11874/scouser73) from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367514/hiding-icons-in-the-top-bar/367518#367518)

Answer (score 1):

no need to restart lightdm after uninstalling, so:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove indicator-messages; killall indicator-messages-service
```