# How do I hide the icons on the top panel?

Tags: indicator

**Hey guys,**

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Asus U46E-BAL6 laptop.

There are a few icons in the tray up top that I dont use, and I was wondering how I could remove them.

For example, I never need to use the mail icon or keyboard icon.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: There is no tray in Ubuntu anymore and there probably never was. The icons are called indicators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the Mail icon, open the **Terminal**, and copy & paste the command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove indicator-messages
```

Now press **Enter** and enter your password, then press **Enter** once again

Now you need to restart lightdm with the following command in the **Terminal**

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Press **Enter** and enter your password then press **Enter**, lightdm will flash and the Mail icon will no longer show.

- [How to remove the Mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

As for the Keyboard icon, follow the answer given by Novine.

Answer (score 7):

I know you can remove the keyboard icon by going to System Settings | Text Entry , then unchecking *show current input source in the menu bar* (checkbox in the bottom left).

As for mail, see scouser73's answer.